# What is the difference between (p!=q ) and !(p==q) in java

Tags: java

I would be thankful to you if you answer this question.... its is an icse class 10 standard question.

I need to know the difference between
**(p!=q ) and  !(p==q)**

Comment: Write the truth tables of both and see if there exists differences.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table

Comment: there exist an difference but i cant point it out ... can u??

Comment: @ZouZou i wrote the truth table and i'm getting both expressions equivalent for this proble. Have i done anything wrong?

Comment: @maxx777 No, the truth tables are the same. I didn't say they were not ;-)

Comment: @ZouZou so does the only difference lies in the performance? first expression uses single operation while the second expression uses two operations. Or the java compilers are smart enough to optimize them equally?

Comment: @maxx777 You can check the generated bytecode (javap -c yourClass). Both generate the same, (see TJCrowder answer).

Comment: @ZouZou well i checked IsidroGH's answer first :P

Comment: thx thx very much i understood.... but i dnt understand why 3 down-vote to my q... is it really a bad question???

Comment: @SusmitLaha I didn't downvote the question, but it's probably because you didn't show any research effort before asking.

Comment: and the time taken for output will be the same???

Comment: @SusmitLaha Depends how smart the compiler is. But `!(p==q)` may be marginally slower if its not optimised to `(p!=q)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are two different [operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) here:

```
x != y
```

checks that x is not equal to y, whereas

```
!(expr)
```

uses the unary negation operator (`!`) to check that `expr` is not true. So your first expression checks that *p is not equal to q*. Your second expression checks that the expression *p equals q* is not true. These are (of course) equivalent.

Comment: probably the best answer so far!

Comment: Yep! the difference is the number of operators used to get to the same result. My initial gut reaction was "there is no difference", how wrong my gut was.

Answer (score 8):

> I need to know the difference between (p!=q ) and !(p==q)

In Java, there basically isn't any.

`p!=q` determines whether `p` is not equal to `q` and gives us a `boolean` (`true` if they're not equal, `false` if they are).

`!(p==q)`, in theory, first determines whether `p` and `q` are equal and gives us a `boolean` (`true` if they are, `false` if they aren't) and then *inverts* that `boolean` (giving us  `true` if they're not equal, `false` if they are equal).

I said "in theory" because I wouldn't be surprised if the compiler ended up emitting the same bytecode for both expressions, provided they're simple variables and the condition is as simple as shown.

---

Yup, same bytecode is emitted for both:

```
iload_1
iload_2
if_icmpeq   [address]
```

Loads the values and does the "jump if equal" operation.

Answer (score 2):

For `(p!=q )` you have:

```
true!=false--->True
true!=true---->False
false!=false-->False
false!=true--->True
```

For `!(p==q )` you have:

```
!(true==false)--->True
!(true==true)---->False
!(false==false)-->False
!(false==true)--->True
```

So as you see there is no difference

Answer (score 2):

They are functionally equivalent but the bytecode is different.

The first one might be more efficient(depending on the compiler) as the check is a side effect of a XOR op. But the in second one, a comparison is made and depending on the result a `true` or `false` is set.

With ECJ compiler (compliance level 1.7):

```
a=(p!=q)
12: iload_2
13: iload_3
14: ixor
15: istore_1

a=!(p==q)
24: iload_2
25: iload_3
26: if_icmpne     33
29: iconst_0
30: goto          34
33: iconst_1
34: istore_1
```

Comment: I'm curious to know that whether you have just convertd the expressions into machine code by yourself or is it the actual conversion that takes place in java?

Comment: It's the actual conversion (JDK 1.7): javap -c

Comment: well i'm using jdk8 and i'm getting same result for both the expressions. Same expression as stated by TJCrowder.

Comment: i tried it using JDK7 and i obtained the same result as earlier.

Comment: you're right, with the JDK compiler it's the same but using ECJ (Eclipse) is different.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to know the difference between (p!=q ) and !(p==q)

Both are logically same in **Java**, checking for condition`p` is not equal to `q`

Comment: Why the downvotes? *in Java* these *are* equivalent!

Comment: @Dariusz :Yes, I clearly stated, **in Java**, both are same. Not sure why this was down voted.!

Answer (score 0):

### (p!=q)

is the value of p is different from q

### !(p==q)

The opposite value of whatever the statement (p==q) gives
ie.

if p is equal to q it returns false

and true if not.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to know the difference between (p!=q) and !(p==q) ?

(p!=q)

> Checks that if`p`is not equal to `q`,then make it true

!(p==q)

> (p==q) Checks whether Both are equal, then make it true. Negation operator
>    (!) makes the inverse of the boolean result. i.e false.
>    That naturally makes it is equal to `(p!=q)` since both expression returns true when p is not
>   equal to q

Answer (score 0):

I think the difference is that you can know two numbers aren't equal even if you didn't check the whole number.

```
(p!=q)
```

will stop at the first difference

```
!(p==q)
```

will check if they are fully equal before complementing the result

Answer (score 0):

It the same thing, you can try to write the truth tables like theese:

```
(a  !=   b)
 0   0   0
 1   1   0
 0   1   1
 1   0   1
```

and

```
 !  (a  ==   b)
 0   0   1   0
 1   1   0   0
 1   0   0   1
 0   1   1   1
```

As you can see, the `0, 1, 1, 0` is result of `!=` and it is resutl of `!( ==)`

Answer (score 0):

```
 p != q implies that p is not equal to q
 !(p==q) implies first execution of statement p==q and then the negation of the boolean value return after execution of first statement
```

Suppose p = 5 and q = 5

1>

```
p != q: In this case, result of execution of the statement will be false.
```

2>

```
!(p == q): In this case, result of execution of the first statement (p == q) will be true. Then negation of true will be false
```

Suppose p = 5 and q = 6

1>

```
p != q: In this case, result of execution of the statement will be true.
```

2>

```
!(p==q): In this case, result of execution of the first statement (p==q) will be false. Then negation of false which will be true
```

Answer (score 0):

Truth table:

p q !p !q  For (p != q)  For !(p == q) i.e equivalent to (!p) != (!q)

0 0  1  1   cond false    cond false

0 1  1  0   cond true     cond true

1 0  0  1   cond true     cond true

1 1  0  0   cond false    cond false

Answer (score 0):

Practically, there is not any difference between `(p!=q)` and `!(p==q)`.

They both will return `true` if `p` is not equal to `q` and `false` if `p` is equal to `q`.

Answer (score -1):

**In Java**, where there is no operator overloading, there is no difference between `(p!=q)` and `!(p==q)`. **In Java all operators are strictly defined. They follow the mathematical logic rules to the letter.**

However, in languages with operator overloading, like `C++`, these may not be equivalent, since the operators `!` and `!=` may be defined to do something which does not follow the rules of mathematical logic.

These would be translated to:

```
(p!=q)  :   p.operator!=(q)
!(p==q) : ! p.operator==(q)
```

Notice the `!` operator is applied to a bool variable, not an object.

Answer (score -1):

`(p!=q)` first checks whether `p` and `q` are equal or not and then it gives the Boolean data type.

Whereas.. `!(p==q)` first checks whether `p` and `q` are equal or not and gives the Boolean data type and then inverts that Boolean.